# Magento Un merge JS and CSS file

Tags: magento-1.9, php, javascript, css

i have merged my magento CSS and JS via the admin backend,after that i was remove the CSS and JS merge option.

After when i look the view source it like be one single line.
see the image below for your better understanding.
[image]

How to overcome with this,help me to rectify my problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your screenshot shows that you have installed fooman speedster extension (or may be any other extension which merger css and js ).
disable/uninstall it and flush the cache

Comment: once i disable no one of the css and js calling, and i can not enable it again via the admin, i was clearing catch in var/catch folder. pls share your idea

Comment: Edit /app/etc/modules/Fooman_Speedster.xml (change true to false). Save and refresh the Magento cache. 

Don't try to disable the output of Fooman_Speedster under Configuration > Advanced - it will make your site unusable! (This is a limitation of Magento's implementation of the disable feature).